# Latex Page Details (Contents of a Individual Page)

Tags: floats, automation

Is it possible to get the details of a individual Page, say for example, what are all the figures and tables and figure citations and table citations present in Page number 3, which will in turn helpful to stop my Figure and Table placement after bibliography, please guide

Comment: `\clearpage` before the bibliography.

Comment: If given \clearpage before bibliography, it retains figure before bibliography, but also clears the page before bibliography and text area is blank after figures, how to rectify that

Comment: I cannot guess in which way the page details could help with problem of floats placements. Move the floats, relax the options, relax the rules, reduce the number of floats, use `\FloatBarrier` (`placeins` package), ... This is a too open question. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and most polular related questions.